# Best way to perform unstructured text search in MySQL using FULLTEXT Index

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have a large MySQL table with 20mm records of sales and 10 or so columns. Two of the columns are **POSTCODE** and **STREET**. I have configured the table so that i have a FULLTEXT index defined on these 2 columns. My problem is when I search this the table using the following query, I get a bunch of random results where I expect to get much closer matches... for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(postcode, street) AGAINST ('W4 RAVEN' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Yields a bunch of results (see top 5 below)

| postcode | street |
| --- | --- |
| WS5 3PZ | RAVEN ROAD |
| WD18 7DA | RAVEN CLOSE |
| DE55 5NR | RAVEN AVENUE |
| IP28 7LF | RAVEN CLOSE |
| WD18 7DB | RAVEN CLOSE |

When in fact, if I run this query, I get the below result, which looks like a much more relevant result than the above to me... ?

```
SELECT postcode, street  from table1 where postcode LIKE "W4 5EQ%" LIMIT 5
```

| postcode | street |
| --- | --- |
| W4 5EQ | RAVENSCROFT ROAD |
| W4 5EQ | RAVENSCROFT ROAD |
| W4 5EQ | RAVENSCROFT ROAD |
| W4 5EQ | RAVENSCROFT ROAD |
| W4 5EQ | RAVENSCROFT ROAD |

Am I misunderstanding how the search works?

I would expect both of the queries above to return very similar results. The reason I  want to use the first one though is because sometimes the user may just search **RAVEN** and sometimes just **W4**, so I dont want to limit them to the column type.

Edit to clarify: Given my table has records similar to what the second query is giving, I would have expected the first query to give something more similar to that than what it returned (a 'closer' match)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to write that comparing the two queries' results is like comparing apples with pears!

In the first query you search for a part of a postcode **and** a part of the street name. Not sure why you are surprised that it returns rows where the searched string appears in the street name column! Not to mention the fact that W4 is probably ignored as it is too short for a word. The default minimum word length is 3 for innodb tables. If you reduced this limit to 2 and rebuilt the fulltext index, then your search results coud also be more accurate.

In the second query you search for a specific postcode only, therefore your results will be more specific as well.

Please remember, fulltext search does not behave like google search! It does not use machine learning or similar data scince techniques to guess the relationship between different parts of the searched expression!

Comment: Thank you Shadow. Do you have any advice how to efficientaly search the text in my first query to get the results in the second? essentially a fuzzy type of search on multiple columns! Appreciate there may not be a short answer...

Comment: This has nothing to do with efficiency! If you want fulltext search to match exactly that you typed, then you need to use '"W2 SEQ"' (note the extra double quotes). You still need to adjust the minimum word length. You must read fulltext search chapter in mysql manual, these properties are documented there!

Comment: be honest, if just want pattern matching, then it may be better to concatenate the two columns and use like instead of fulltext search.

Comment: Doesn’t full text on 2 columns do the same thing? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: As you can see from your question, no, they don't.

Comment: I'm starting to think parsing my free form text using an address library might be the easier solution. Then atleast when I do a partial LIKE search I know what columns to look in

Answer (score 0):

- I suspect that `IN NATURAL MODE` is inappropriate for addresses.  Suggest `IN BOOLEAN MODE`, perhaps with plus (`+`) in front of each term.
- The default `innodb_ft_min_token_size` value is 3.  Hence, "W4" will be ignored.  You could change that, however, it would mean rebuilding all FT indexes.
- I suggest having a space in the postcode is counter-productive.  As you insert data, remove all punctuation from it.  Then search for `+W4*`.
- For a query that only checks prefixes, `LIKE 'W4%' *may* be faster than FT.
- Mixing FT searching and non-FT searching *may* be slow.

Comment: Thank you Rick .. to provide some colour... the user can also search "RAVENSCROFT W4", "W4 5EQ",  "RAVENSCROFT ROAD W4", etc

Comment: @rex - I am not familiar with that style of postcode; what does "W4" mean to your user?

Comment: W4 is a prefix to the full postcode in London that specifies the general area. Full code would be W4 5EQ

Comment: @RickJames UK post codes have 2 parts separated by space. The first part (W4 in the question) determines a larger area, while the second part indicates a quite exact location within the larger area, like a block of street. It is very common in the UK to search for addresses by the outcode (the first part of the post code) only.